# key is not available in cleaned data in clean method of form in django

Tags: python, django

I have below ModelForm class.

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from tenant.models import EventsModel
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.utils import timezone
from django import forms

class EventsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EventsModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean_start_date_time(self):
        # can not be before than now.
        data = self.cleaned_data
        print(data)
        start_date_time =  data.get("start_date_time")
        now_date_time = timezone.now()
        if start_date_time < now_date_time:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                _('Start time has passed.'),
                code='invalid',
            )
        return data

    def clean(self):
        # end date can not be before or equal to start date time
        # data = super(EventsForm, self).clean()
        data = self.cleaned_data
        print(data)
        start_date_time =  data.get("start_date_time")
        end_date_time = data.get("end_date_time")
        if start_date_time >= end_date_time:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                _('End time should be after start time.'),
                code='invalid',
            )
```

`clean_start_date_time` raised an error because `start_date_time` is in past.
`start_date_time` is available in `clean_start_date_time` method but is not available in `clean` method. **Why is this happening?**

I printed the cleaned data in both the methods, there is difference in cleaned data. **Why is this difference?**

cleaned data in `clean_start_date_time` :

```
{'tenant_sys_id': None, 'name': 'dfghj', 'start_date_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 21, 13, 20, 23)}
```

cleaned data in `clean` :

```
{'created_by': None, 'last_updated_when': None, 'last_updated_by': None, 'tenant_sys_id': None, 'notes': 'g', 'name': 'dfghj', 'created_when': None, 'end_date_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 31, 14, 20, 29)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not there because you raised an error in `clean_start_date_time` instead of returning. Note that you did exactly what you are supposed to do. You should never assume that a field will be present in `clean`; the same thing would have happened if the user had not filled in data for that field. Check the value is present before doing anything else.

Comment: start_date_time is present in POST data. It is also present in clean_start_date_time. But is not present only in clean method.

Comment: Yes, for the reason I gave. This is *expected behaviour*.

Comment: Got the point. If clean_start_date_time is raising an error then start_date_time will not be present in cleaned data after that. In this particular scenario, second error will not be shown until user corrects the first error. Is there any way I can show both errors to user assuming data is entered in such a way that bot errors should be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/), your function clean_start_date_time should return the cleaned field value *start_date_time*.

Your function now exits either with an exception, or with *cleaned_data*. That is the reason that *cleaned_data* is not the same in the *clean* method and the *clean_start_date_time* method:

> The clean_fieldname() method is called on a form subclass
>   – where fieldname is replaced with the name of the form field attribute.
>
> ...
>
> This method should return the cleaned value obtained from cleaned_data, 
>   regardless of whether it changed anything or not.